# Show div in every browser apart from IE

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I've got a message in a div that I need to show on the webpage that isn't viewed in Internet Explorer. I have tried the standard `<!--[if !IE]>` and a few of the other suggestions, but to no avail.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Internet Explorer 10 and greater, I suppose...

Comment: Firstly, explain why you need to do this, as there might be better ways to fix it. Secondly, give more details of what you tried and what issues you faced.

Comment: Let me guess... the message says "This page best viewed in some other browser"....? Seriously, don't do that. Browser detection like that takes us all the way back to the 1990s. This is exactly the kind of thing that left us with the legacy of IE6 all those years.

Comment: Thanks all. I am working with MS Visual Studio and we want to display a message that basically says that some of the features that we've included might not work on other browsers (we haven't tested them all) but we have tested them all in IE 8+. At the moment, if you're using IE <8, you get redirected to another page and told to upgrade, but we still want to allow people to use the system in another browser, so long as they know that we can't offer support for it.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor - Let me know if that answer works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I don't recommend you do it this way!**

First of all, [browser detection is evil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh273397%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and you should avoid it where possible. Feature detection using something like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) is far more user-friendly. Remember that *a lot* of users (all mobile users, Mac users, Linux users) will not have the option of using IE even if they want to.

**Having said that, it IS possible...**

OK, let's say your HTML is this:

```
<div id='notOnIE'>Some content, do not display on IE.</div>
```

**Hide the `DIV` in IE9 and earlier:**

First of all, let's detect IE9- and make this DIV invisible in IE:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <style type='text/css'>
        #notOnIE{ display:none; }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

**Hide the `DIV` in IE10:**

Now, we need to hide the DIV in IE10, add this to your CSS stylesheet:

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
    #notOnIE{display:none;}
}
```

*Microsoft deliberately broke if IE tags in IE10 because it supports a lot of HTML5 standards and people were (ab)using those tags to make their websites intentionally break in IE rather than render half-working versions.*

[Working demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADMcj/).

**Note: If you want to show the `DIV` on IE7 and earlier:**

In your comment you suggested that you have tested IE8 and higher, but IE7 and even 6 still have use, so if you want to show the `DIV` on those too, you can use version detection:

```
<!--[if gte IE 8]>
    <style>
        #notOnIE{display:none;}
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

[Working demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NEtHV/).

Comment: this works perfectly! Thank you very much! I have spent ages researching this, a good few hours and nothing like this has come up. Thank you, once again!

Comment: @ChrisTaylor No problem, but please try Modernizr at some point, it will help you a lot when developing a website for the mass market. IE is less than 40% of the market now.

Comment: Thanks @LightningDust. I'm investigating Modernizer at the moment.